# Joint normal distribution, independence and correlation..

Tags: statistics

With two random variables, A and B=(2C-1)A, for A~N(0,a), C~Bernoulli(1/2), and A and C are independent.

A question contains proving Cov(A,B)=0, |A|=|B| and A+B is not normally distributed.

I managed to show Cov(A,B)=0, |A|=|B|. But I cannot show Why A+B is not normally distributed. I could go until A+B=2CA. I am not sure waht 2CA means or not sure if there is another approach.

Anyone can help me?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: *Hint.* $A+B$ is $0$ “half of the time”.

Answer (score 0):

$P(2CA=0) \geq P(C=0)=\frac 1  2$. Since normal distribution is continuous we must have $P(2CA=0)=0$ for $2CA$ to be normally distributed.

Comment: Thank you for helping me. I have two questions about your answer. Why (2=0)≥(=0)?  I have no knowledge about product of two random variables. Can I think as P(2CA=0) is greater than P(C=0) since P(2CA=0) is a probability C or A are zero?  Also why must we have (2=0)=0 for 2 to be normally distributed.

Comment: Is the reason that (2=0)=0 normal distribution is continuous so it has zero probability at a single value of random variable?

Comment: @Horselook Yes, that is exactly what I am saying.